# Python 3 Ошибка "Удаленный интерпретатор инициализирован повторно"

Tags: python

Друзья,только изучаю программирование. Изучаю по книжке. Там был такой пример: Вычислить площадь фигуры,ограниченной графиками y=x и y=x^2. И так же приведен листинг программы:

```
n=500
dz=1/n
pts=0
i=0
while i<=n:
    x=dz*i
    j=0
    while j<=n:
        y=dz*j
        if y<=x and y>=x**2:
            pts=pts+1
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
s=pts/((n+1)**2)
print ('Square of the figure:',s)
```

Однако у меня вместо результата площади, получается значение `s=1` и пишет что "Удаленный интерпретатор инициализирован повторно"

Вот описание метода из книжки:

> "При вычислении площади фигуры мы будем исходить из следующих
>   соображений. Во-первых, замечаем, что область, ограниченная кривыми,
>   полностью попадает в единичный квадрат с левой нижней вершиной в точке
>   начала координат и правой верхней вершиной в точке с единичными
>   координатами. Если мы случайным образом выберем точку внутри этого
>   квадрата, то она с некоторой вероятностью попадает в область, что
>   ограничена кривыми (то есть попадет внутрь "лепестка"). Теория
>   вероятностей утверждает, что эта самая вероятность равна отношению
>   площадей "лепестка" и квадрата. У квадрата с единичной стороной
>   площадь равна единице. Поэтому площадь "лепестка" (которую нам
>   необходимо вычислить) равняется вероятности, с которой случайным
>   образом выбранная точка попадает внутрь "лепестка". Это будет
>   "во-вторых". В третьих, если взятгь очень много случайных точек,
>   равномерно распределенных по квадрату, и вычислить отношение
>   количества точек внутри "лепестка" к общему количеству точек, в идеале
>   получим оценку, близкую к вероятности попадания случайно выбранной
>   точки внутрь "лепестка". Мы всю эту процедуру немного модифицируем и
>   поступим следующим образом. Вместо того чтобы генерировать случайные
>   точки, покроем весь квадрат равноотстоящими узловыми точками.
>   Посчитаем, сколько их попало внутрь "лепестка" (то есть области,
>   ограниченной кривыми), и поделим на общее количество точек. Это и
>   будет результат. Программный код, в котором реализован такой подход,
>   представлен в листинге"

Comment: Через что запускаете код?

Comment: Всё работает https://repl.it/IsOG   , проблема в самой среде разработки которую вы используете.

Comment: Я использую Pyscripter-в книге его рекомендовали.Однако я заметил, что он почему-то не хочет работать с русским текстом,ошибки выскакивают типа таких непонятные. Можете посоветовать в какой среде лучше работать?

Comment: И что это за среда,на какую Вы ссылку дали? Вообще отлично все там работает.

Comment: @ПавелТитов, просто попробуйте писать в любом редакторе с подсветкой кода, а запускать двойным щелчком мыши (или из редактора, если он это позволяет). Также можно попробовать Jetbrains PyCharm (Community Edition или Educational Edition). У вас проблема скорее всего именно в Pyscripter.